# What is the difference in ListViews and other Views when using findViewById?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

When finding most views in Android, one can usually use `findViewById(R.id.my_id)` where the id looks like `android:id="@+id/my_id"` in the XML file.

When using any kind of ListView, we have to use `findViewById(android.R.id.my_id)` and in the XML we use `android:id="@android:id/my_id"`.

Can someone please explain to me why this is and why it makes a difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> When using any kind of ListView, we have to use findViewById(android.R.id.my_id) and in the XML we use android:id="@android:id/my_id".

No, you do not. In fact, what you have there most likely will not compile.

*If* you are inheriting from classes like `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`, *then* you need to use a framework-defined `@android:id/list` / `android.R.id.list` identifier for the `ListView` that those classes will manage. That is so `ListActivity` or `ListFragment` can find the `ListView` that you want it to manage for you.

In any other circumstance, you are welcome to name your `ListView` whatever you like, as with any other widget or container.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom views you usually define you own ids `@+id/your_own_id`. Elements from libraries use the same notation. However elements from the SDK use the `android` prefix.

If you include a `ListView` in your layout it is common to give it a standard id `@android:id/list`. Some SDK classes expect standard ids. For example if you had a custom layout for a `ListFragment` the layout HAS TO include a `ListView` element with a standard id.